# Historical interracial fictional romance. A black girl with red hair travels in time and falls in love with a viking

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book about a black girl with red hair who is whisked into the past and falls in love with a Viking.

I've tried google and goodreads but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: There are very many time travel viking romance novels (most of them soft-core porno); https://www.romance.io/topics/best/time%20travel,vikings/1 - We need a little more to go on.

Comment: @Valorum how many of them have redhead black girls as main characters, though?

Comment: @Jenayah - Lol. Surprisingly many of them have black characters. I'm not sure whether they're all redheads

Answer (score 2):

[*The Viking Wants Forever*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YSP97YI) (2015) by Koko Brown?

It features an African-American girl (not in summary but in the Amazon comments) who is sent back in time by Loki and ends up with Eirik Sigurdsson, a Viking.

Google Books has no eBook and I found no illicit PDFs to search, so I couldn't determine if she is a redhead.

It seems to be porn.